# Where to hook a function that brings files before the build process

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, vue.js, build, nuxt.js

I need my Nuxt app to pull SCSS and image files from s3 before the build process.

I can't find the right place to plug this functionality into. It seems like the hooks are not made for that and the middleware is for after the build.

Comment: Why would u want to do it within nuxt? Why not pull files u need and then build nuxt?

Comment: When I deploy the app to a server it runs the build process, so instead of adding sctlripts to the server it seems simpler to do it in the nuxt server